# How to find the Array function when using Rets

Tags: php, arrays, associative

I have an array problem and have been working on this for months.

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT COUNT(*) AS $total FROM 
wp_realty_listingsdb');
print "<pre>";
print_r($results);
print "</pre>";

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [$total] => 25
        )
)

$results = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
wp_realty_listingsdb');
print "<pre>";
print_r($results);
print "</pre>";

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [COUNT(*)] => 25
        )
)

$cars=array("Volvo");

print "<pre>";
print_r($cars);
print "</pre>";

echo $cars[0];

Array
(
    [0] => Volvo
)

Volvo
```

So as it goes I have no problem using the echo to get the cars variable but no matter what I do I cannot get the variables from the above arrays...
I have tried all of the following to no avail.

```
echo $results['total']
echo $results['0']
echo [0][total]
echo array[0][total]
echo $results['count']
```

You can see the image of the arrays here as to how they look:

- Example #1: [(first one using count(*) AS $total)](http://screencast.com/t/sTs6vxX2)
- Example #2: [(second one using count(*))](http://screencast.com/t/5zhcr3bQO)
- Example #3: [(third one and no problem volvo)](http://screencast.com/t/5zhcr3bQO)

Really appreciate any help what so ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the 1st one like the following way

```
$results[0]->{'$total'}
```

Same for the second one

```
$results[0]->{'COUNT(*)'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your getting an object back in the first two examples. To have the query return an array, try adding the [optional second argument](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results):

```
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS $total FROM wp_realty_listingsdb';
$results_old_way = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
$results_new_way = $wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_A);
```

Compare the difference between `$results_old_way` and `$results_old_way` to see the difference. It should make more sense to you the new way.

Comment: Thanks TunaMaxx looks great but dummy me could not figure out how to print the answer. I tried echo $results_new_way and old way with negative results even via print and print_r.. nothing from either.. would love to understand more about this.. how do I make the result print just simply 25 which is the answer....

Comment: I didn't want to spin up a WordPress to test last night as I was going to bed, but the `$results_new_way` should have return an array of arrays, instead of an array of objects. @Bokul's answer told you how to get the value while still as an object.